# Sending a email in a angularjs function with emailyak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

I want to send a email with a javascript function. I created a emailyak account this for and can send a email with a curl command.

Like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"FromAddress" : "info@mydomain.simpleyak.com","FromName" : "My App","ToAddress": "blabal@gmail.com","Subject" : "Test","TextBody" : "Hello"}' https://api.emailyak.com/v1/my_api_key/json/send/email/
```

But if I do the equivalent call from javascript side it does not work.

I use:

```
.controller('AppointmentCtrl', function($scope, Services) {
    $scope.sendMail = function() {

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.emailyak.com/v1/my_api_key/json/send/email/',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            data: {
                "FromAddress" : "info@mysubdomain.simpleyak.com",
                "FromName" : "My App",
                "ToAddress": "blabla@gmail.com",
                "Subject" : "Subject",
                "TextBody" : "Body"
            }
        };

        $http(req).

            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                alert("Success");
                //return data;
            }).

            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                alert("Error:"+JSON.stringify(status));
                //return false;
            });
    }
});
```

In my html I use:

```
<button ng-click="sendMail()" class="button button-positive button-block">
    Absenden
</button>
```

This is a ionic framework application and I run the test in the iOS Simulator. I checked the internet connection of the simulator and it works. If emailyak has some problems the call wouldn't work from the terminal.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind when looking at your sample code is that the $http module is not being passed into the controller function.

I think this line:

```
.controller('AppointmentCtrl', function($scope, Services) {
```

Should be:

```
.controller('AppointmentCtrl', function($scope, $http, Services) {
```